# Is there a text component that can sets the tags in the text?

Tags: javafx-8

I am looking for a component which of the typed text the user is looking for regex. If it finds the indicated text, the text will be tagged.
 It is possible to configure input / text edytor components to work this way?

as a result, as I write the day of the week in the text, it will be marked as a tag. It looks like it can be a text field with the ability to set patterns so that tags are tagged.

For example in Jira application, when we enter a text and input component recognize that the text contains First and last name that highlights these words

Comment: So are you looking for a JavaFX component like [TextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html)? Also, I don't understand what you mean by tagging text. Do you mean highlighting it, like when you drag the mouse over text in a `TextArea` component?

Comment: For example in Jira application, when we enter a text and input component recognize that the text contains First and last name that highlights these words

Comment: So you want a component that the user can enter text into, which automatically highlights parts of the entered text, correct?

Comment: @Abra that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't think such a component exists. I suggest writing some appropriate listeners to add to `TextArea`.